# Cassandra CQL update vs Object Mapper update, which will have an impact on read performance

Tags: cassandra, cql3

Let us consider we have below table, in reality lets assume this table has 40+ columns

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee_by_id (
    employee_id text,
    first_name text,
    middle_name text,
    last_name text,
    date_of_birth date,
    joining_date date,
    role_id text,
    role_name text,
    dept_id text,
    dept_name text,
    reporting_manager_id text,
    reporting_manager_name text,
    created_on timestamp,
    created_by text,
    updated_on timestamp,
    updated_by text,
    status text
    PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)
);
```

> There is a scenario to update department details, columns dept_id and
>   dept_name.

There are 2 ways this update can be done,

**1. Cassandra Object Mapper**

> Assuming the object mapper works on whole object, it updates all the
>   columns including the ones that were not modified in above said
>   scenario.

**2. CQL update query**

```
UPDATE employee_by_id set 
    dept_id = 'A100', 
    dept_name = 'General Accounts', 
    updated_on = '2017-04-24T00:00:00.000Z', 
    updated_by = 'arun' 
WHERE 
    employee_id = 'E04500';
```

**Understanding:**

1. After updating, when the record is read in Cassandra, the read
   operation checks each and every column to find out which is the
   latest based on the timestamp of these columns.
2. If the above stated employee_by_number table is updated using object mapper, then cassandra needs to check/compare all 17 columns to find the latest of all these.
3. On the other case of updating only 4 columns using CQL
   update, cassandra needs to check/compare only these 4 columns to find the latest of these.

**Question:**

> 1. Is my understanding correct?
> 2. Which is preferred way of updating, using CQL update to set 4 fields or updating all the columns using object mapper even though
>      only 4 fields are being modified?
> 3. If both updates are good and doesn't affect performance, is there any scenario in which we should not use object mapper for updates?
> 4. CQL update vs Object Mapper update, which will have an impact on read performance when updates are done only on few columns.

Answer (score 0):

**Using CQL Query**

If you can insert/update using CQL query, It's best. But you have to manually write query code for every combination of updated.

**Using Object Mapper**

You don't have to write query for every combination of insert/update. object mapper automatically take care of that.

But remember

**When Saving data to Cassandra, By default Cassandra Object Mapper save all the field declared in the table entity.**

If you haven't set a field value, default value is null, except primitive field. Thus null value will be inserted into cassandra with Object Mapper, tombstone will be generated. Tombstone take up space and can substantially increase the amount of storage you require.Querying tables with a large number of tombstones causes performance problems and it causes Latency and heap pressure.

Read More About Tombstone : https://opencredo.com/cassandra-tombstones-common-issues/

By the way you can change the  mapper default save option :

```
mapper.setDefaultSaveOption(saveNullFields(false));
```

Which will ignore the null value field when inserting.

Another issue with Object Mapper, Suppose you have declared some field with primitive type. If you haven't set these field, Default value 0 will be used (Primitive type default value is 0).

Now for the first time you have set these value let's say grater than 0. So Object Mapper save these value. After that you have not specified these value, so your value will be replaced by the default value 0.

Comment: My questions are not about setting null values, it's about storing or setting same value to a column. To say in other words, it about updating fields with same value and it's impact. Can you please read the question and update your answer appropriately?

Comment: @ArunBC CQL query is best to use, but if you use Object Mapper, how the object mapper suppose to know that which field have updated or not ??  I have just shown that

Comment: Can you answer my 4 questions at the bottom of my post? It's about read performance when doing partial update using CQL vs full update using object mapper. If you think you answered already no worries